# Codeigniter Simple Login Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this Codeigniter error as i tried to implement simple log in application but when i insert Email and password to log in form it respond with the same form and i can't log in

this is my Model function :

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
 }
 function login($email,$password)
 {
  $this->db->where("email",$email);
  $this->db->where("password",$password);

  $query=$this->db->get("user");
  if($query->num_rows()>0)
  {
   foreach($query->result() as $rows)
   {
    //add all data to session
    $newdata = array(
      'user_id'  => $rows->id,
      'user_name'  => $rows->username,
      'user_email'    => $rows->email,
      'logged_in'  => TRUE,
    );
   }
   $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
   return true;
  }
  return false;
  }
```

Controller :

```
class User extends CI_Controller{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
 }

 public function index()

 {
  if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
  {
   $this->welcome();
  }
  else{
   $data['title']= 'Home';
   $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
   $this->load->view("registration_view.php", $data);
   $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
  }
 }
 public function welcome()
 {
  $data['title']= 'Welcome';
  $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
  $this->load->view('welcome_view.php', $data);
  $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
 }
 public function login()
 {
  $email=$this->input->post('email');
  $password=md5($this->input->post('pass'));

  $result=$this->user_model->login($email,$password);
  if($result) $this->welcome();
  else        $this->index();
 }
```

View :

```
<div id="content">
<div class="signup_wrap">
<div class="signin_form">
 <?php echo form_open("user/login"); ?>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="" />
  <input type="submit" class="" value="Sign in" />
```

Comment: You sure password is not encrypted?

Comment: What happens? What did you try and what was the outcome? What happens when you echo out the newly added vars etc?

Comment: when i enter Email the and password it respond with a clear form and can't direct to the other function , and i found mySql database encrypted as Email =0 and password =9193ce

Answer (score 1):

How does a user signup? You're checking the user_name session variable to see if it's blank instead of email, which is what was actually typed in, in order to show the welcome screen. Email and password can be completely filled in in your DB, but since you're checking the users name instead in your conditional:

```
if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
```

if that comes out as blank, you'll see your index()
If you insist on using this method, ensure the username column in your user table is populated. Or, use the email column in this conditional instead, whcih given your implementation I would recommend, since they're logging in with an email address and not a username (implying a single name instead of an email address)

```
if(($this->session->userdata('user_email')!=""))
```

Additionally, you could also check your logged_in session variable too, that's what it's there for. Still going over your code to find other issues, but those stick out to me as potential problem areas.

A little more information on your part would definitely be helpful. Have you dumped out your session data or row data to see what's actually being returned? email=0 doesn't make sense

Comment: thanks man i tried your suggest but i still got the same problem .